# Using the word "type" in redux actions

Tags: redux, naming-conventions, naming, redux-actions

I'm trying to use Redux with React Native recently. As far as I know, the word "type" is restricted by the Redux, that is, if there is a property in my property, it won't work together.

```
{ 
  type: 'MODIFY_USER',
  gender: 'male',
  type: 'normal_user', // <= this is the type of the user specified to modify,
}
```

Since every naming is perfectly mapped in my code. How should I adapt with this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the "payload" approach:

```
{ 
  type: 'MODIFY_USER',
  payload: {
    gender: 'male',
    type: 'normal_user', // <= this is the type of the user specified to modify,
  }
}
```

Comment: @Ziac - I've upvoted this answer as this seems the more suited approach - perhaps more to your needs.

Comment: Thank you, that's a great hint :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you build an adapter which takes your modelled data and adapts it to the API?

For example, say you have your original code base. Once you have modelled your data, then pass it through an Adapter.

You can map the new `type`, say `user_type` to the original.

For example:

Incoming:
Component > Adapter > Redux

Outgoing: Redux > Adapter > Component

With an adapter you don't have to change your code to suit other APIs. For example if you want to pass your user data to Facebook, you can create a Facebook Adapter in your application.

I think the good thing about adapters is that you never change your code to suit various APIs, you only create the adapters (which creates an easier flow, rather than manipulating your data within your current application)

Comment: Thanks for the instant reply! I will definitely try to use a adapter. Since I'd like to go with conventions, the properties of the action builder seems to be working like "parameters" of a function or say an action. Yet for some reason, the word "type" is used as a keyword which somewhat forbids me using this general word as my property name of my data models. Just wondering "adding another Adopter layer" for this to be the best approach for these problem or not, since the word "type" is quite common to see and use.

Comment: I can see where you're coming from - but as 'type' is a very vague, term - should this be passed as the object without a context? I would rather pass a model of user data, which has a property 'type'. That means your action has `type` and `data`